# Rails: elegant way to get user_agent in a before/after callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

I have an `:after_update` callback that records edits to one of my models.

I'm wondering if there is an elegant way to get the user_agent into in this callback when the edit came from a web request.

I know it's in the model, which doesn't have access to the request object.  And it doesn't have to be edited from a web request.  For example, if edited from the console, it would be fine if user_agent were nil in that case.

The only alternative I can think of is to find every controller action which might update the model and make the call from there, but this is a huge code base that is changing rapidly so it would be easy to miss something this way.

Maybe there is a clever way to put an attr_acessor on the model called `user_agent` (not stored in database) and ensure every controller action populates this on an edit?  But not sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Elegant I'm not sure about, but I believe Rails will use 1 thread per request (spawns it off to process it), so you can do

```
Thread.current[:my_user_agent] = request.user_agent
```

and that is accessible all the way through the app for the duration of that request. I'm also fairly sure that's not documented behaviour, so you might have issues if Rails modifies it.

Comment: That is definitely creative/scary :)  Would you set that in a before_filter in application_controller?

Comment: Yep. I set it in a before_filter. It's a fine technique I think as long as it's not mission critical (for example, displaying an IE stylesheet). If you wanted to display a nice error message, what's the worst that could happen if the behaviour was altered? For what you describe, its probably good enough...just make sure you don't trust what's in it (check for nil etc) and have sensible fallbacks. I've never had a problem with it for minor tracking.

Comment: Hmm...this seems to persist across requests when using thin.  Are you using mongrel or passenger or what web server?  I'm thinking maybe thin doesn't use a new thread per request.

Comment: Are you sure? Looking into the source, it's how rails implements default scopes internally, and how I18n tracks the language you have selected. I'd be surprised if neither of those work with Thin (though I use webrick/unicorn for local development).

Comment: In Rails, a threads typically gets re-use to handles multiple request. Setting a variable in Thread.current makes it thread local not request local and will be persisted across multiple request. As for Thread.current being used in Rails code source look at this ticket, especially the comment towards the end https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6246-timezone-is-broken-in-most-every-version-of-rails-including-3x

Comment: Hmm, thanks for that Yacc, very interesting. I was refering to the implementation of default scopes: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/default.rb#L122 but, looking at what the code does, that fits the same criteria. Thanks for the clarification! @BrianArmstrong, does that help you?